# What does "strategic defence review" means?

Tags: word-usage

In phrase "strategic defence review" which one is correct?

1. review on strategic defence
2. startegic review about defence

Thanks

Comment: It could be both, but it's most likely that a review of strategic defence is meant.

Answer (score 1):

At the level of *English language*, the expression is inherently ambiguous, but since it normally refers to a [specific review conducted by Britain in 1998](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_Defence_Review), we can easily establish that *that* one was a review of our ***strategic defence*** current capabilities and anticipated future requirements.

I'm not sure exactly what it would mean if the review itself were to be described as *strategic*. Perhaps it could imply the review was part of the then-current government's strategy for remaining in power. Or maybe part of a strategy by the military to secure future funding, or by the relevant Civil Service departments to maintain their influence on such policy areas. But none of those seem particularly credible scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to find which element(s) has been modified?(rather than meaning)

Comment: As I said, *at the level of English language, the expression is **inherently ambiguous***, so obviously if you don't take account of possible *meanings*, the answer to your question is ***No***. Only credible meanings *in context* can tell you whether a "light green bulb" is a bulb coloured light green, or a green bulb which is light (probably, in *weight*).